# MUnit Coverage not showing exception block coverage

Tags: mule-studio, mule-esb, munit

we are using munit "mock with error" message processor to simulate an error in rest api call. we are able to see that the log messages placed in the exception block are being logged , but the munit coverage report does not show the loggers part of the coverage report. Is it a known bug in MUnit? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Please add an example MUnit script to the question, with the mock, flow, logs with the error and the coverage report.

Comment: Also MUnit and Mule versions.